# Powershell - how to check if installation is running in user or system context

Tags: powershell, permissions

I have packaged an application with the App Deployment Toolkit.

I install the application with the command:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $setupx64 -ArgumentList "/silent /install" -verb runas
```

That works. But only if the installation is running in the user context and not in the system context. If the installation runs in the system context (via SCCM) I need this command without the parameter *-verb runas* => otherwise it does not work

```
Start-Process -FilePath $setupx64 -ArgumentList "/silent /install"
```

How can I check in my script if the installation is started in the user context or in the system context?

Thank you!!

BR

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example snippet of code to determine if the current security context is NT AUTHRORITY\SYSTEM:

```
if ($env:USERNAME -eq "$env:COMPUTERNAME") {
  # do the thing that's special for the system
}
else {
  # do whatever you want for the user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, "How can I tell if the user is running as Administrator or not?"

If so, the following code should work.

```
$StartProcessSplat = @{
    FilePath = $setupx64
    ArgumentList = @(
        "/silent",
        "/install"
    )
}
$User = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$isAdmin = (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $User).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
If ($isAdmin) { $StartProcessSplat['verb'] = 'runas' }
Start-Process @StartProcessSplat
```